# Extrair valores de um array e montar um ou outro

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DDF
            [2] => 00001778BRASILIA
            [25] => 00032433NORTE (AGUAS CLARAS)
            [44] => 00000000
            [68] => RUA
            [102] =>   00655588MANACA
            [124] => R MANACA
            [145] =>  71907270NS
            [179] =>  

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DDF
            [2] => 00001778BRASILIA
            [25] => 00052443RESIDENCIAL FLAMBOYANT (PLANALTINA)
            [39] => 00000000
            [63] => CONJUNTO
            [96] => 00742211A
            [119] =>   CJ A
            [141] =>  73366243NS
            [142] =>   

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DDF
            [2] => 00001778BRASILIA
            [25] => 00032434SUL (AGUAS CLARAS)
            [44] =>   00000000
            [68] => RUA
            [102] =>   00575809MANACA
            [124] => R MANACA
            [145] =>  71936500NS
        )

)
```

Resultado esperado

```
Array(

  [0] => Array
        (
            ['cidade'] => BRASILIA
            ['bairro'] =>NORTE (AGUAS CLARAS)
            ['logradouro'] => RUA MANACA
            ['cep'] =>71907270

        )
    )
```

Comment: O array vem da onde? é possível mudar o nome das chaves na definição?

Comment: o array vem de um arquivo txt, resultado obtido com esse codigo             echo "<pre>";
    print_r($narr);
    echo "</pre>";

Comment: Qual a relação do primeiro como o segundo array? Qual o critério para a utilização das informações? O que você perguntou, pode ser respondido com: $array2[$indicey] = $array1[$indicex]. Explica melhor teu problema.

Comment: Eu desenvolvi a solução para seu caso, mas notei que o indice 68 e o 102 não se repete em todos os array.
Então isso gerou um erro na rotina que eu fiz, mas se você quiser eu posto aqui para você e você trata as exceções dos índices.

Comment: pode postar Duque...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, desenvolvi sua solução, porém precisa tratar os erros que vão surgir, pois notei que os índices não são comuns.
Fica por sua conta tratar essas exceções.

```
$data  = array (
    array
        (
            0 => 'DDF',
            2 => '00001778BRASILIA',
            25 => '00032433NORTE (AGUAS CLARAS)',
            44 => '00000000',
            68 => 'RUA',
            102 =>   '00655588MANACA',
            124 => 'R MANACA',
            145 =>  '71907270NS',
            179 => ''
        ),
    array
        (
            0 => 'DDF',
            2 => '00001778BRASILIA',
            25 => '00052443RESIDENCIAL FLAMBOYANT (PLANALTINA)',
            39 => '00000000',
            63 => 'CONJUNTO',
            96 => '00742211A',
            119 =>   'CJ A',
            141 =>  '73366243NS',
            142 => ''

        ),
    array
        (
          0 => 'DDF',
          2 => '00001778BRASILIA',
          25 => '00032434SUL (AGUAS CLARAS)',
          44 =>   '00000000',
          68 => 'RUA',
          102 =>   '00575809MANACA',
          124 => 'R MANACA',
          145 =>  '71936500NS'
        )   );

    $newArray  =  array();

    $i  =  0;

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $newArray[$i]['cidade']      =   preg_replace('/[0-9]+/',"", $value[2] );

            $newArray[$i]['bairro']      =   preg_replace('/[0-9]+/',"", $value[25] );

            $newArray[$i]['logradouro']  =   $value[68] . ' ' . preg_replace('/[0-9]+/',"", $value[102] );;

            $newArray[$i]['cep']         =   preg_replace("/\D/","", $value[145] );

            $i++;

    }

    print_r( $newArray );
```

Comment: O problema é que o CEP nem sempre é 145, em um deles é 141, assim como outros valores, por isso  não seria ainda uma resposta 100% certa, mas não vou negativar por isso, obviamente aparenta está correta para "alguns casos" e está correta para o exemplo dado pelo autor da questão, irei testa-la depois para dar +1 =].  Mas, acho não precisa de `preg_replace` em todos os casos, o CEP pode usar o `(int)$value[145]`, neste caso, em outros apenas é removido os números, portanto pode usar `preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $value[xx])`, acredito eu, fica mais compreensível.

Comment: O código está correto, o `preg_replace`/`REGEX` usado não está correto. Substituindo o `preg_replace` pelo informado no comentário acima ele funciona corretamente. Sugiro que corrija usando o método mencionado acima ou por outra solução equivalente.

Comment: @Inkeliz, foi isso o que disse a ele, ele vai ter que tratar essas exceções. O preg_replace tem várias 'faces', no entanto, fica a critério do programador usar, conhecimento a mais nunca é demais, sua opção também é válida.

Comment: @Inkeliz o regex do preg_replace funciona sim, testei e aqui está funcionando corretamente, a título de melhor entendimento, vou alterar ele para a forma descrita por você, assim podemos ajudar outros usuário.

Comment: Aqui obtive erro usando isso. Ele manteve os números. Veja em http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbdfe3cd77f53d559bcd35e7fa052d4c6f2d1649.

Comment: @humberto, note que foi alterado o regex do preg_replace. Desta forma está melhor compreensível.

Comment: @Inkeliz, os notices é porque alguns dos índices não são comuns. Isso foi mencionado no comentário da pergunta e no cabeçalho da resposta. Já alterei os preg_replace.

Comment: Desculpe, não havia visto isso. Mas, já dei +1.

Comment: Visto @Duque, funcionou aqui, usei array_values para redefinir os indexes,  obrigado pela colaboração de todos vocês.

Comment: Humberto, nao foi nada